# How do I parse html to remove an element and return only title in its place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html snippet like this

```
Hello<i class="emoji emoji_smile" title=":smile:"></i><i class="emoji emoji_angry" title=":angry:"></i>World
```

Now I want to parse this html and it must grab the value of the title and replace the  tag only with the title then return the result like this using javaScript or jQuery

```
Hello:smile::angry:world
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to replace DOM element with new content:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#title .emoji').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).attr('title'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title">Hello<i class="emoji emoji_smile" title=":smile:"></i><i class="emoji emoji_angry" title=":angry:"></i>World</div>
```

Comment: I think I have a lot to learn, Can't believe the solution is so simple. Have to improve my logic too thank you very much.